# Mongodb query based on item at specific position in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to run a query where an item at a specific position in an array needs to be compared.

For example, consider the GeoJSON format for storing location data.

```
//sample document from collection user
{
    name: "Some name",
    location : {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates : [<Longitude>, <Latitude>]
    }
}
```

How would I query users located at a specific longitude?

I cant seem to find anything in the documentation which can help me do the same.

Queries I have tried:

```
db.users.find({"location.coordinates[0]" : -73.04303})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your query to the following

```
   db.users.find({"location.coordinates.0" : -73.04303})
```

Comment: What id the index is a variable, not `0`?